# mongoose schema , Invalid schema configuration

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have a schema of user that contain an array of movie
i create a new schema of Movie
but i get error of invalid schema configuration.
what i'm doning worng?

```
enter code here
```

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Movie = require("./movie-model");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const User = new Schema({
  firstName: { type: String, required: true },
  lastName: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  movies: { type: Movie },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("user", User);
```

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Movie = new Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    time: { type: String, required: true },
    rating: { type: Number, required: false },
    priorety: { type: Number, required: true },
  },
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("movie", Movie);
```

Answer (score 0):

in movie-model

module.export = Movie

instead of

module.exports = mongoose.model("movie", Movie);

Answer (score 0):

User has many movies

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Movie = require("./movie-model");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const User = new Schema({
  firstName: { type: String, required: true },
  lastName: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  movies: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "movie",
    },
  ],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("user", User);
```

I invite you to read more about [One-to-Many Relationships with Embedded Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/)

Comment: i can do it like this?  const User = new Schema({
  firstName: { type: String, required: true },
  lastName: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  movies: [Movie
  ],
});

Answer (score 0):

You need to done referencing in User collection

```
movies: [
type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
ref: 'user'
]
//instead of doing that
movies: { type: Movie },
```